# Inputting analogue data via USB

Tags: usb, android-input-method

I am trying to build this device which takes analogue input from the earth , converts them into electrical impulses which I wish to input into a android smartphone for data analysis. I initially thought about using the 3.5mm jack of the android device. Apparently Android does not support input through the 3.5mm jack.  So I decided to use the USB cord as the input. 
Now my question is will my android phone or tablet directly able to read the USB data, or has it to be fed through some microcontroller??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, are trying to measure soil conductivity and find out if your plants need water? which is easy. Or are you trying to build a heart monitor? which is a bit more complex.

Anyway if you are interested in conductivity measurement with Android, you may want to have a look at this device, it is driver free and works on Android.

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-sensors/yocto-knob

I believe V-Alarm is using them as well

http://www.valarm.net/blog/use-valarm-sensor-for-flood-warning-and-water-detection

Comment: yeah my device can be used as a heart monitor though i had some other implementation in mind because my circuit is not robust enough to elliminate noise. 
coming back to the point, so I have this circuit which takes electrical signals from the human body and amplifies them and is ready to input them via the 3.5 jack into a pc. However I want to imput this via the USB. Can you give me a idea of how to do it??