# real time data recording in android via USB

Tags: android, usb, libusb

I am trying to build this oscilloscope circuit that generates analogue signals at various frequencies. Say for example the 512 Hz button is pressed then it will generate a sine wave at 512 Hz, if 256 Hz is asked for then it will generate it etc.

So my friend wanted to build a oscilloscope application on Android which will show the waveforms that are being generated. Since android does not have 3.5 mm audio input I guess the output of the circuit must be fed through the USB port.

Can someone tell me how to feed the data through the USB? Do I have add additional circuitry to convert the analogue signals into digital? If so, can anyone send me the link of a simple such circuit (I am a young student and havent much soldering experience)?  Also how does my friend need to modify the app so that accepts USB input?

We do not mean audio input because we don't need high sample rates. Sample rate of 2 kHz is sufficient for our purposes.

Comment: I would go for some usb sound card, making your own usb device is REALLY hard, it is not something you can solder and make tick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inputting analogue data via USB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864306/inputting-analogue-data-via-usb)